# Visual Studio 2010 not creating a sub project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna

The **error** I get when I make a new project is:

> A problem was encountered while creating a sub project 'WindowsGame1'
>   object was not set to an instance

I checked all over StackOverflow, so please don't link other articles saying
 "Did you check this?"

I uninstalled .Net framework, XNA, VS2010, VSC#, rebooted, and reinstalled them, still no effect. Can someone help? I can't even access projects I made before this! In the debugging window it says

> Object was not set to an instance